# Adding SQL Rows from two CTEs

Tags: sql

I have two CTEs that I've unioned two produce the following result:

```
date    serie   events
2019-05-09  hello   175
2019-05-02  hello   196
2019-05-09  goodbye 1
2019-05-02  goodbye 1
```

I want to add the events per day together so that

```
2019-05-09 total 176
2019-05-02 total 197
```

At the moment I have something like:

```
with hello_events as (
  --- actual logic not interesting ---
 )
 , goodbye_events as (
  --- actual logic not interesting ---
  )
select * from hello_events
union all
select * from goodbye_events
```

If I want a third set of results being the sum, I assume I need to do something like

```
with hello_events as (
  --- actual logic not interesting ---
 )
 , goodbye_events as (
  --- actual logic not interesting ---
  )
select * from hello_events
union all
select * from goodbye_events
union all
select date, "total", sum(events) as events
from hello_events, goodbye_events
where hello_events.date = goodbye_events.date
```

But that's clearly not correct. What am I missing?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Missing GROUP BY. And you should UNION the results before aggregation, not join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `group by`, as below:

```
with hello_events as (
  --- actual logic not interesting ---
)
 ,goodbye_events as (
  --- actual logic not interesting ---
)
,tmp_result as (
select * from hello_events
union all
select * from goodbye_events
)
select
    date,
    'total',
    sum(events)
from
    tmp_result
group by
    date
```

Comment: thanks so much, I had something similar earlier, but got sucked down the wrong path after some syntax errors

Comment: Yep, you have completed 90%'s job in fact. :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace your inner query with this:

```
select date, 'total' as total, sum(events) as events
from (
        select * from hello_events
        union all
        select * from goodbye_events
    ) t
group by date
```

Working example at:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b0846/4